# Connect Four OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

This code is very rough, incomplete, and is not professional in any way.  I have recieved:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at ConnectFourGame.main(ConnectFourGame.java:63)

anytime that I try to enter a column this shows up.  I have been looking over my code and so has my father, and we are unable to find where the error is.  Any help would be great!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ConnectFourGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] grid = new int[6][7];
        int i, j, temp, player=0, inarowl=0, inarowr=0, temprow=0, inarowd=0, tempcol=0;
        boolean legal = true;
        boolean gameover = false;
        //Initializing game board
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
            for(j=0;j<7;j++)
                grid[i][j] = 0;

        //ALL GAME LOGIC
        do {
        i=0;
        j=0;
            //PLAYER 1
               //check for diagonals next
            do {
                i=0;
                j=0;
                player=1;
                //player places chip
                temp=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "pick your column( 0 / 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 )"));
                for(i=0;i<6;i++)
                    {
                        if(grid[i][temp]==0)
                            //detects lowest available chip slot in the column for placement
                        {  // and turns that spot into a box owned by the player
                                grid[i][temp]=player;
                                legal=true;
                                temprow=i;
                                tempcol=temp;
                                    break;  
                        }else legal=false;
                    }
            }
            while(!legal);
            inarowl=0;
            inarowr=0;
            tempcol=temp;
            do
            {
            tempcol--;
            inarowl++;
            }while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player); 
            tempcol=temp;   
            do
            {
            tempcol++;
            inarowr++;
            }while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player);

            do
            {
            temprow--;
            inarowd++;
            }while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player);
            if (inarowl+inarowr-1>=4||inarowd>=4)
            gameover=true;
            //PLAYER 2
                //check for diagonals next
            do {
                i=0;
                j=0;
                player=2;
                temp=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "pick your column( 0 / 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 )"));
                for(i=0;i<6;i++)
                    {
                        if(grid[i][temp]==0)
                        {
                                grid[i][temp]=player;
                                legal=true;
                                temprow=i;
                                tempcol=temp;
                                    break;  
                        }else legal=false;
                    }
            }
            while(!legal);
            inarowl=0;
            inarowr=0;
            tempcol=temp;
            do
            {
            tempcol--;
            inarowl++;
            }while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player); 
            tempcol=temp;   
            do
            {
            tempcol++;
            inarowr++;
            }while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player);

            do
            {
            temprow--;
            inarowd++;
            }while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player);
            if (inarowl+inarowr-1>=4||inarowd>=4)
            gameover=true;          
        } while(gameover==false);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I am seeing is that you are using a `do... while(condition)` loop. The *problem* in this case is that you are first subtracting integers and then, using that same integers to access memory locations.

The problem with this approach is that since you are checking before you subtract, you are trying to access a negative memory location. To go around this problem, use `while(condition)` loop instead. This will allow you to perform the check *before* you make the array operation, which would allow you to break the loop in time.

Comment: A I see what you are saying.  I figured that by subtracting 1 from the inarowl+inarowr that it would still count the same amount.  I will try this out!

Comment: @user3914322: I made an omission in my response. You might also need to ensure that the values never go below 0.

Answer (score 0):

This  piece of code might triggers an out of bound exception : if grid[temprow][0] == player, then tempcol is decreased (to -1), and grid[temprow][-1] will be evaluated.

```
do
{
  tempcol--;
  inarowl++;
}while(grid[temprow][tempcol]==player);
```

In your while condition, you must also ensure that the array index is still within the bounds of the array.

```
 while (grid[temprow][tempcol] == player && tempcol > 0 && tempcol < grid[temprow].length)
```